# Indestructible com.docker.db.exe

Tags: docker, windows-10

I am running Docker on Windows 10 Pro. When I started Docker it told me there was an update so I told it to install and restart (Docker nor machine) then went to lunch.

When I cam e back the updated had failed with the following error:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.db.exe' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at LightweightInstaller.UnpackArtifactsStep.<DoAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at LightweightInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<HandleD4WPackage>d__19.MoveNext()    
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at LightweightInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<ProcessAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
```

I traced the problem to the com.docker.db.exe file being in a strange state. Even as administrator I can not delete the file or see who owns it or any of the security settings.

I used FindLockingProcess.psm1 in power shell but that reported

```
PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...m.docker.db.exe:String) [Test-Path], UnauthorizedAccessException
```

So I tried unlocker and that reported the file locked and unlocking it I was able to delete the file - apparently - it 'reappeared in the locked state!

I have performed a disk scan - no problems

Rebooted - same issue.

I just cant delete this file and docker will not reinstall so not able to work!

Its only the com.docker.db.exe that is the problem, been able to delete all other files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to delete the file. No idea what was going on.

To delete the file I rebooted into safe mode - pressing space while clicking restart.

This enabled me to delete the file and it not not reappear.

Boot to normal mode and Docker installed.